# how to make UITextView text alignemnt right and Justified at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview

I need my long text inside UITextView to be aligned right and Justified at the same time . But I notice that I could just select right or justified .How can I have both Alignments for my UItextView at the same time ?

Comment: Please describe your purpose for this. So we can help you.

Comment: Same problem here :/

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this (Swift 3,4):

```
var yourString = String()
let yourTextView = UITextView()

let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: yourString)
            let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraph.baseWritingDirection = .rightToLeft
            paragraph.alignment = .justified
            attrText.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraph, range: NSMakeRange(0, yourString.length))
yourTextView.attributedText = attrText
```

Comment: Awesome! You save my day. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best option available for your requirement at the moment is this 
[image]

Comment: @pankarj I need right alignment too.Not just Justified

Comment: Yes i know. Just check the difference between the second option and fourth option. whichever suits best to your needs

Comment: It alignes the last line to left, but it should be to right as per Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve both alignment at the same time, But you can add a right alignment when entering the text in the textview, after you finished editing the textview set the text alignment to justify,

So Whenever you start editing the textview use right alignment and once you have finished editing set justify , simple :)

Comment: what do you mean by editing? I'm not doing editing.I'm just setting a text to UITextView

Comment: @sali I thought you will edit the textview by start typing on it

Answer (score 0):

Hack it!(kidding:)). Set text alignment to the justified, set width that is less than screen width, move the text view to the right edge of the screen. Voila, it's right aligned and justified. Good luck!

Comment: Could you make a snippet of it ?